# Insert if Update row_count()=0

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, sql-update, sql-insert

I need to update a table row, but if it dont exist, it must be created.
I´ve tried with that code but returns errors:

```
UPDATE creature SET name="Bip" WHERE guid = 1;
IF ROW_COUNT()=0 THEN 
    INSERT INTO creature (guid, name) VALUES(1, "Bip"); 
END IF;
```

I need to update before inserting, so i cant use "INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE …"
Thats becouse i supose that Insert query will be skiped if ROW_COUNT is 0.

What can i do to fix it?

Comment: Are you writing a stored procedure? That's the only place you can do this. That's why you're getting errors.

Comment: Im using query strings in c++, do you mean that?

Comment: [Stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html) are a different way of executing a query. They're like small programs you can run on the server. The syntax of these is dramatically different from regular SQL queries. They give you a lot more capability, but the downside is they need to be loaded in advance.

Comment: OK thanks for the info, im going to try it

Comment: I'n not sure what you're intending here. Is it to set a name if one exists with that ID, and if not, then to insert that record? That's precisely what `INSERT IGNORE` is for.

Comment: No, it must update the row name, but if the row doesn´t exist Insert creates it

Comment: So basically the same thing, only you're thinking of the two operations in reverse order?

Comment: Yeah, im not sure if the order matters, but i will use many more Updates than inserts. That means less operations if update goes before insert

Comment: Don't worry about it. MySQL will figure it out for you.

Comment: Really? Interesting :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`:

```
INSERT INTO creature (guid, name) VALUES (1, "Bip")
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name)
```

That should insert a new row, or if there's a collision on `guid`, then it'll update the name.

Note you need to have a `UNIQUE` index on `guid` for this to work. If there's no `UNIQUE` constraint then it will insert duplicates.